# How do I use SQL Server to use a single column to fill two separate columns in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, multiple-columns

I have two tables:

```
dbo.Products [ItemID] [ProductID]
dbo.Accessory [PartItemID] [AccessoryItemID]
```

Both columns in `Accessory` table match the `ItemID` column in the `Products` table.
How do I get the `Accessory` table to show the appropriate `ProductID` instead of the `PartItemID`, and `AccessoryItemID`?

For example:

```
ItemID=1, ProductID=Part, PartItemID=1,AccessoryItemID=5
ItemID=5, ProductID=Accessory, PartItemID=5, AccessoryItemID=NULL
```

I would like the output to look like this:

```
ProductID=Part, PartItemID=1, Accessory=Accessory, AccessoryItemID=5
```

Comment: @User.....you'll need to be more specific with your description of your tables.  Please display the table name and include all columns for each table name.  Then when speaking of a column name, qualify it with the table name....i.e., Products.[ItemID], Accessory.[PartItemId].  That will make your question more clear

Comment: `JOIN` the two tables

Comment: Can you please explain (or re-phrase) the following:  "**Both** columns in Accessory table match the `ItemID` column in the `Products` table".

Comment: Is it correct in assuming `ProductID` column is actually expressing a Product *Name*?

Answer (score 1):

As @PM77-1 said, but more specifically, `JOIN` as necessary on all your keys.  You can join to the same table multiple times.

In your case:

```
SELECT p1.ProductID as PartItem
     , a.PartItemID
     , p2.ProductID as AccessoryItem
     , a.AccessoryItemID
  FROM dbo.Accessory a
  LEFT JOIN dbo.Products p1
       ON p1.ItemID = a.PartItemID
  LEFT JOIN dbo.Products p2
       ON p1.ItemID = a.AccessoryItemID
```

This will output the corresponding products as Part and Accessory per row in your Accessory table.